# Do your Planar Shepherd and Druid levels stack when determining the size of creature you can Wild Shape into?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, class-feature, multi-classing, wild-shape, creature-size

The Planar Shepherd class states:

> **Wild Shape (Su):** Your druid levels stack with your planar shepherd class levels for the purpose of determining the number of daily uses, the maximum HD and size (but not creature type), and the duration of your wild shape ability.

The Druid class spells out sizes of animals you can turn into related to druid level: Small and Medium at 5th level, Large at 8th level, Tiny at 11th and Huge at 15th.

Would a 7th-level druid, 1st-level Planar Shepherd be able to wild shape into a Large animal?

Comment: @MatthieuFoltzer See [this FAQ](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6533/321) for why your comment was removed. Thanks!

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you doubt that the word *size* in your quote refers to the property you’re asking about, or did you just miss it? It’s fine if it’s the latter, but if you saw it and there’s a particular reason you aren’t sure it means what you are asking about, it would improve the question to explain that and it would allow answers to address those particular concerns.

Comment: The reason i was questioning it was because I always thought of the size increase being a class feature similar to say timeless body, where even though certain things stack you don't get all the class features. Thus I was thinking of size increase as somewhat separate from the actual wild shape ability. It's just not something I am used to seeing most druid prestige classes I have read will stack for uses per day and I had never seen one that basically functions as +1 level of druid's existing wild shape class feature.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## Yes

The only restriction on Planar Shepherd is the creature types that levels in base Druid grant you. As the ability says it grants you: # of Uses per day, HD, duration, and *size* all stack with the base Druid class.

Planar Shepherd does grant you additional creature types at 3rd and 9th levels (Magical Beast, and Outsiders/Elementals native to your chosen plane.)

So a Druid 7 / Planar Shepherd 1 would most certainly be able to wild shape into a Large animal.